# How to assign a hostname for development to docker-compose containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am really a newbie in docker but I need to setup it for local development. I am using docker-compose to run few containers and I would like to assign a hostname for local development. This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql
      - db-mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
#      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-api-platform}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-api}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://username:password@db-mysql:3306/dbname?server_version=8
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|caddy$$
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

  pwa:
    build:
      context: ./pwa
      target: api_platform_pwa_prod
    environment:
      API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy
      NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy

  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: api_platform_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
      - pwa
    environment:
      PWA_UPSTREAM: pwa:3000
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: udp
        
  db-mongodb:
    # In production, you may want to use a managed database service
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_mongo
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test_mongo
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongodb_db_data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mongodb/data:rw
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"      

  db-mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
#    security_opt:
#      - seccomp:unconfirmed
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
        protocol: tcp

volumes:
  php_socket:
  mysql_data:
  mongodb_db_data:  
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

and this is Caddyfile

```
{
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
}

{$SERVER_NAME}

log

# Matches requests for HTML documents, for static files and for Next.js files,
# except for known API paths and paths with extensions handled by API Platform
@pwa expression `(
        {header.Accept}.matches("\\btext/html\\b")
        && !{path}.matches("(?i)(?:^/docs|^/graphql|^/bundles/|^/_profiler|^/_wdt|\\.(?:json|html$|csv$|ya?ml$|xml$))")
    )
    || {path} == "/favicon.ico"
    || {path} == "/manifest.json"
    || {path} == "/robots.txt"
    || {path}.startsWith("/_next")
    || {path}.startsWith("/sitemap")`

route {
    root * /srv/api/public
    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt:///data/mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Allow anonymous subscribers (double-check that it's what you want)
        anonymous
        # Enable the subscription API (double-check that it's what you want)
        subscriptions
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }
    vulcain
    push

    # Add links to the API docs and to the Mercure Hub if not set explicitly (e.g. the PWA)
    header ?Link `</docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation", </.well-known/mercure>; rel="mercure"`
    # Disable Google FLOC tracking if not enabled explicitly: https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc
    header ?Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"

    # Comment the following line if you don't want Next.js to catch requests for HTML documents.
    # In this case, they will be handled by the PHP app.
    reverse_proxy @pwa http://{$PWA_UPSTREAM}

    php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
    encode zstd gzip
    file_server
}
```

with this configuration I have api platform running on caddy at `https://localhost` and the pwa app (next.js) running on `https://localhost:3000`.

What I would like is to have the backend on `https://api.mysite.local` and the pwa on `https://www.mysite.local`. Also how can I setup certificates locally to have SSL fully working (for the API)?

Comment: you need to modify the hosts file in your development environment so `api.mysite.local 127.0.0.1` and then create the zertificates for `api.mysite.local`

Comment: this does not work. Also how to discriminate between api and www?

Comment: Could you try to give your host name the same name as a container for example `pwa` and add entry `127.0.0.1 pwa` to your hosts file and then try again initite the ssl connection?

Comment: in this case you need zertificate that issued for `pwa` host

Answer (score 1):

First things first - top level domain *.local* is reserved for *mDNS* (also known as *Avahi* and *Bonjour*), so I wouldn't use that to avoid confusion.

Let's go with *api.mysite.local.dev* and *[www.mysite.local.dev](http://www.mysite.local.dev)*.

Second - I'm not seeing port 3000 being exposed anywhere in your Composefile, so I'm going to assume you're using Caddy as a reverse proxy for both the frontend and the backend.

To start with you need to create two virtual hosts in your Caddyfile - something like:

```
www.mysite.local.dev {
    reverse_proxy php:80
}

api.mysite.local.dev {
    reverse_proxy pwa:3000
}
```

Then all you need to do is use your computer's hosts file to point both *api.mysite.local.dev* and *[www.mysite.local.dev](http://www.mysite.local.dev)* to *127.0.0.1*.

As for TLS, you need to generate a wildcard certificate for **.mysite.local.dev*, then mount it in the container and point Caddy to it using the Caddyfile. Assuming you mounted the certificate and the key as */etc/tls/cert.pem* and */etc/tls/key.pem*, you'd need to update the CaddyFile above to:

```
www.mysite.local.dev {
    reverse_proxy php:80
    tls /etc/tls/cert.pem /etc/tls/key.pem
}

api.mysite.local.dev {
    reverse_proxy pwa:3000
    tls /etc/tls/cert.pem /etc/tls/key.pem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Konrad. Caddyfile is in a folder called docker/caddy. does this means I need to rebuild the container? PWA is on port 3000 when I run `npm run dev` so maybe it is a node server?

Comment: I updated the question with my caddyfile. could you please tell me where to place the vhost definition? I already tried to put them at the bottom with no luck.

Comment: @user3174311 If you start PWA using `npm dev run` it's not using Docker. Which means that when you run both `npm dev run` and `docker-compose up -d` you end up with two instances of PWA - one running on your local machine and one running inside pwa container. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user3174311 Your Caddyfile already defines one vhost: `{$SERVER_NAME}`. This vhost redirects requests to either pwa or php containers depending on whether they match @pwa. You cannot use Dockerized Caddy as a reverse proxy to PWA running directly on your computer, which your question suggests is what you want.

Comment: ok fine. I hope I will be able to do this in production when deployed?

Comment: can you tell me, given the Caddyfile I posted above, how can I setup SSL for php? thanks. btw caddy shuold issue cerfificates automatically but for some reason my instance doesn't.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, by default, Caddy tries to use Let's Encrypt to provision the certificates - that approach, however, only works for real domains, accessible from the internet. You need to either generate the certificate manually, mount it inside the container and use the `tls` directive to tell Caddy where it is or use `tls internal` to instruct it to generate a self-signed certificate. Place the `tls` directive immediately below `log` directive. https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls